# Exhaustive join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Here is a capture of an SQL architecture:

[image]

I want to select all the keywords related to a given path. This is a join, and I know how to do that. My problem here is that I want each keywords to be associated to all the icons related to the given path, not just only one.

Let's take an example, let's consider that the path named **warning** is related to 3 icons (warning-circle, warning-triangle and warning-square):

- **warning-circle** (keywords = `warning`, `mark` and `circle`)
- **warning-triangle** (keywords = `warning`, `mark` and `triangle`)
- **warning-square** (keywords = `warning`, `mark` and `square`)

Performing a join will select all the keywords : `warning`, `circle`, `triangle` and `square`.

The keywords I want to select are only `warning` and `mark` because all the icons are linked to these keywords. I don't want to select circle`or`triangle`or`square` because they are not related to all the icons.

Any idea on how to perform that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any sample data it's hard to be certain but something like this should work:

```
SELECT k.keyword
FROM paths p
JOIN icons i ON i.id_path = p.id
JOIN keywords_icons ki ON ki.id_icon = i.id
JOIN keywords k ON k.id = ki.id_keyword
WHERE p.name = 'warning'
GROUP BY k.keyword
HAVING COUNT(i.id) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.id)
                      FROM paths p
                      JOIN icons i ON i.id_path = p.id
                      WHERE p.name = 'warning'
                      GROUP BY p.id)
```

I've created a [demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dzuF7ZXqK79XuzGJE2ks1J/1) where I've tried to emulate what you describe so you can see how the query works.

Comment: Sounds great, but the following error appears : "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" in my DB, not in DBFiddle ...

Comment: @Fifi sorry about the slow reply (been night time here), good to see you figured out the issue. I've approved your edit and also updated the demo.